# Passing form data to another form via url in lotus

Tags: agent, lotus

I am working on a new web app in lotus/domino.  I am newer to lotus/domino programming, so forgive me for not knowing something simple.

What I am trying to do is display a table of information, with one of the columns containing a link.  The link is formatted like [http://server/app.nsf/form?openform&ideaNum=1&var2=foo2]

How can I retrieve the information from the url, to get information from a view or a document?

So far I have tried to access the query string in the webQueryOpen event, but lotus runs the agent before the DOM writes to the browser, the query_string isn't available.

I am not sure how else to get information from one form to another in lotus.

Thanks for the help.

-Kris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're passing multiple params in the query_string, you can get Domino to do a bit more of the work for you. There's an Function command - UrlQueryString - that can format the params into a list, delimiting at the "&".

E.g. server/app.nsf/form?openform&ideaNum=1&var2=foo2
becomes a list:

openform
ideaNum=1
var2=foo2

To use it, on the destination form create a multi-value text field called something like "QryStringList". 
Set it to be computed when composed, and set it's value to @UrlQueryString.

In your WebQueryOpen agent, you can access the params as doc.QryStringList(0), docQryStringList(1) and so on, if you're using Lotusscript.

I'm fairly sure I put this together using info from the IBM/ldd forum, but the exact source is lost in the mists of time and memory, so apologies if I've copied someone's post.

Comment: awesome!  I current have a function to break it out into a variant, then grab x array out of it.  Thanks a ton, I will defiantly start using this!

What happens if var2 is blank?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a follow up, I found that you are able to specify an on form variable named the same as QUERY_STRING.  The variable is actually a reserved term for Lotus, so Lotus pre-fetches the variable before running the information out the browser.

Due to the pre-fetching, you are able to access the url information during the webQueryOpen event.

I hope this helps someone else looking for the same type of functionality.

-Kris